# How to combine those three SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to combine this three queries without giving me the same output ?

The first query is :

```
select   
    vwemployee.directorateName,
    count(vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 
from 
    vwemployee, vwemployeeCourse 
where  
    vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
group by 
    vwemployee.directorateName
```

This is the second query :

select 
       vwemployee.directorateName,
       count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2 
    from
       vwemployee, employeeCourse
    where 
       vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId 
    group by
       vwemployee.directorateName

This is the third query :

```
select 
    vwemployeeCourse.directorateName, sum(vwCourse.cost) as t3
from 
    vwemployeeCourse, vwCourse
where 
    vwemployeeCourse.courseId = vwCourse.Id
group by 
    vwemployeeCourse.directorateName
```

I will be using the combined query to generate a report

- the t1 column should display how many courses this specific directorate took
- the t2 column should display how many employee's under this directorate took this courses
- the t3 column should display how much the courses cost for every directorate

So the total columns of the table of the combined query should be 4 columns

**FYI:** some nice people here helped me to combine the first two queries but it was not sample at all and i didn't succeed to add the third query to them since I am a beginner so please help me with a full simple query to understand it for future references

Comment: If the goal is to merge them so you can use Union clause.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. We can achieve this using NESTED CTEs. You can see here I have created 3 nested CTEs, and in the end I have used all the three CTEs to get your result.

```
with cte1 as
(
select   vwemployee.directorateName   , count(vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 

from vwemployee , vwemployeeCourse 

where  vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 

GROUP BY vwemployee.directorateName
)
,cte2 as
(
select vwemployee.directorateName , count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2 

from vwemployee , employeeCourse

where vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId 

GROUP BY  vwemployee.directorateName
)
,cte3 as
(
 select vwemployeeCourse.directorateName , sum(vwCourse.cost) as t3

 from vwemployeeCourse , vwCourse

 where vwemployeeCourse.courseId = vwCourse.Id

 group by vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
)
select cte1.directorateName, cte1.t1, cte2.t2, cte3.t3
from
cte1 inner join cte2 
on cte1.directorateName = cte2.directorateName
inner join cte3 on
cte2.directorateName = cte3.directorateName
```

Comment: this is what happen when i executed the suggested query   


  : http://i.stack.imgur.com/bMKZW.png

Comment: There was a typo, I have made the correction. Could you please try again?

Comment: Also as @marc_s mentioned, please use joins. I didn't notice that you have used comma separated tables in your queries.

Comment: this is the error message when i used the edited query                                             : http://i.stack.imgur.com/tjoNa.png

Comment: Edited. I copied pasted your query. Accidentally copied your table name along with the column name DirectorName in my last select statement. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Then, given the three queries as written, with no other information, I think I would go for `full outer join` or `union all` with aggregation:

```
with ec as (
      select e.directorateName, count(ec.employeeId) as t1
      from vwemployee e join
           vwemployeeCourse ec
           on e.directorateName = ec.directorateName 
      group by e.directorateName
    ),
    ed as (
      select e.directorateName, count(ec.directorateName) as t2
      from vwemployee e join
           vwemployeeCourse ec
           on e.id = ec. employeeId 
      group by e.directorateName
     ),
     cc as (
      select ec.directorateName, sum(c.cost) as t3
      from vwemployeeCourse ec join
           vwCourse c
           ec.courseId = c.Id
      group by ec.directorateName 
     )
select directoratename,
       coalesce(t1, 0) as t1,
       coalesce(t2, 0) as t2,
       coalesce(t3, 0) as t3
from ((select directoratename, t1, null as t2, null as t3 from ec)
      union all
      (select directoratename, null as t1, t2, null as t3 from ed)
      union all
      (select directoratename, null as t1, null as t2, t3 from cc)
     ) t;
```

Having said that, I don't think this query can actually do anything useful.  Joining two tables on two different keys, and then aggregating by the same key (as for `ec` and `ed`) is not usually done.  If this doesn't produce the results you want, then ask another question, provide sample data, desired results, and a SQL Fiddle.